# Right click functionality in PyQT widget broken from PyQT4 to PyQT5 update

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I previously developed an application with PyQT4, including a QListWidget, with a right-click-pop-up-window that allowed the user to quickly delete rows from the widget.

This was based on code from Stack Overflow: [PyQt: How to get most of QListWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489018/pyqt-how-to-get-most-of-qlistwidget)

Unfortunately, upon upgrading to PYQt5, this functionality is now broken. I get the error: QListWidget object has no attribute 'connect'.

I suspect this is a due to a new implementation in PyQt5, which is quite annoying, although I can't find a simple way to fix this from the new Qt documentation.

Could someone suggest how I might restore my original functionality please?

I'd prefer to not roll back to Qt5 in the interest of future-proofing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyQt5, PyQt4's old-style signals and slots are not supported.

So, to fix the problem, replace the line

```
        self.myListWidget.connect(self.myListWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.listItemRightClicked)
```

with

```
        self.myListWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.listItemRightClicked)
```

and replace the line

```
        self.connect(menu_item, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.menuItemClicked)
```

with

```
        menu_item.triggered.connect(self.menuItemClicked)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and the code is more readable too. Thanks.