# how to sort a list of custom widgets in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5

I have a custom widget with two labels LabelA and LabelB in it. This is added into a QlistWidget. How to sort the list based LabelA or LabelB depending on the user requirements? I would like  to keep labelA and labelB in a tile (styled widget)

I saw this solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489018/pyqt-how-to-get-most-of-qlistwidget)

```
class ListWidgetItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.text() < other.text() # or whatever
```

But i would like to pass an additional argument  to `__lt__`

Comment: Why are you using labels instead of reading/writing the text in the list widget item?

Comment: Use a tree-widget with two columns instead of a list-widget. Then you can simply [sort by the required column](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#sortItems).

Comment: I want to keep labelA and labelB in a tile (styled widget)